# apt-get install mysql-server fails in Dockerfile

Tags: apt, docker

Well this one has me stumped.  Something silly I'm doing I imagine.

In my Dockerfile I have

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install python-dev mysql-server python-mysqldb rabbitmq-server sudo cifs-utils --assume-yes
```

And it fails with

```
Package "mysql-server" has no installation candidate
```

(python-dev installs fine)

But apt-get install mysql-server works from bash.  (and apt search mysql-server shows it as existing.)

This Dockerfile has previously (couple of months ago) worked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spin up an interactive shell inside a container of the image by running:

```
docker run --rm -it python:3.6 bash
```

(If the image doesn't have bash you can use `sh` instead)

You can then search for packages using apt to find which are available. e.g.

```
apt search mysql
```

The package probably exists, just under a slightly different name.

Comment: Thank you.  It's default-mysql-server on this OS.